# the derivative of an integral involving absolute value

Tags: calculus, probability, derivatives

Given a random variable Z with a continuous and compact support, and a function $g(x,y)=E|x-y-Z|$, my aim is to find $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$. I found the following after writing $g$ using an integral and differentiating it:
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x-y-Z}{|x-y-Z|}f(Z)dZ$$

Is my final calculations correct? How can I simplify this expression, so that the final answer is a function of $(x-y)$?

Answer (score 2):

Write $T=Z+y$, then the goal is to find the derivative of
the function $h:x\mapsto\mathbb  E(|x-T|)$. Using the identity $|z|=2z\mathbf 1_{z\gt0}-z$, one can rewrite $h(x)$ as
$$
h(x)=2\mathbb E(x-T;x-T\gt0)-\mathbb E(x-T),
$$
or,
$$
h(x)=2x\mathbb P(T\lt x)-2\mathbb E(T;T\lt x)-x+\mathbb E(T).
$$
Using the density $f_T$ of $T$, one gets
$$
h'(x)=2\mathbb P(T\lt x)+2xf_T(x)-2xf_T(x)-1=2\mathbb P(T\lt x)-1.
$$
Equivalent formulations are
$$
h'(x)=\mathbb P(T\lt x)-\mathbb P(T\gt x)=\mathbb E(\mathrm{sign}(x-T)),
$$
and the RHS is the formula in your post (provided one replaces the faulty $Z$ in the integral by any dummy variable one wants). Introducing the CDF $F_Z$ of $Z$, one gets
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=h'(x)=2F_Z(x-y)-1.
$$
Another, more direct and more general, approach is to start from the deterministic identity
$$
|x-t|=|t|+\int_0^x\mathrm{sign}(z-t)\mathrm dz.
$$
Integrating this with respect to the distribution of $T$ and using Fubini theorem for the last term yields
$$
\mathbb E(|x-T|)=\mathbb E(|T|)+\int_0^xu(z)\mathrm dz,\quad u(z)=\mathbb E(\mathrm{sign}(z-T)),
$$
from which the derivative should be direct.